# jQuery validation separate error labels for a control

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got a requirement to validate an input - if it's empty then show a text under it and an asterisk on the right. So, the labels should be in different containers and have different text. The code below works until you input something and erase, it'll show you two completely identical labels. Are there any ways to create separate labels?

**Markup.**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <input type='text' class='image-name' />
</div>

<input type='submit' />
```

**JS**

```
  var validator = $('form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      if (element.attr('class', 'image-name')) {
        error.addClass('b-gallery__validation-message');
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());

        // creating an asterisk 
        var asterisk = error.clone()
          .addClass('b-gallery__validation-star')
          .removeClass('b-gallery__validation-message')
          .text('*');
        asterisk.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }      
  });
  validator.form();
```

Comment: Read the documentation for the plugin. You're trying to do everything within one callback function.  That's not how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do too much within the `errorPlacement` callback function.  It's only fired upon a validation error to place the message `label` within the layout... it's not fired for all the other things you also want to do.

**I *suggest* that you [read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) for each callback function,** and restructure your code accordingly.

---

**`errorPlacement`** is used for layout.  When an element is invalid, this callback function tells *where* to place the element on the form.  The default is *after* the element being validated.

---

**`success`** is used to control the `label` when the element is valid.  In other words, by default, there is no `label` when the element is valid, so by using this callback, you can generate one.  Typically, people will use this for placing a icon next to valid elements, like a check-mark.

---

**`highlight`** is triggered whenever there is a validation error and it's used for toggling the default error and valid classes on the element being tested.

---

**`unhighlight`** is triggered whenever the validation error is corrected and it's used for toggling the default error and valid classes on the element being tested.  **It's the exact opposite of `highlight` and should be installed whenever `highlight` is installed.**